How to Reduce Exe file size for winforms based vb.net application
We are tasked with optimizing the deployment process of a VB.NET WinForms application currently developed using Visual Studio 2022.
The application’s executable file, which is approximately 84 MB, is currently stored in a shared path, requiring users to download it before they can access the application.
This download process can be time-consuming and may lead to user frustration due to waiting times.
Our goal is to reduce the overall time taken for users to download the client executable
We are exploring potential solutions, such as implementing a separate repository for the executable or utilizing a URL-based download approach through a Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) pipeline.
We welcome any ideas or suggestions that could help streamline this process, improve user experience, and minimize download times.
I also explored below publish options but not sure which of them should be used to downsize the published code ?VS 2022 Publish options

Have you embedded large resources like images, etc.?

Do you have a specific goal in wanting to reduce the size and do you have a reasonable reason to believe it's feasible? It's 2024, and by-and-large, you really shouldn't need to worry about a few MBs here or there.

yes, We have embedded large resources like images, but still file size become little large due to lots of dependencies like Nuget packages, Reportviewer

yes, we have  a specific goal to bring down size from 84 mb to at least 50 mb or something, this will reduce waiting time for users

There is all kinds of software to distribute and install software on Windows machines automatically. Contact your IT/Windows administrator department. If your company is any reasonable size, they already have solutions in place for this.

Agree with you..but.this is actually the published code which contains all the nuget packages,dll and other resource file required to run the application.  We need  just to cut down the size.by.any techniques

I suspect the compiled code is rather small. Even large projects with 250,000 lines of code and a gazillion nuget packages tend to not even be 20 megs in size. So, this suggests the resource files have HUGE amounts of assets - most likley images or some such. So, I would move out the assets (pictures) to a separate folder, and then you can re-deploy and re-update the .exe file, and it will probably be only 20 megs, or even smaller in size. You then need a strategy such as on project startup to optional copy down some of the new picture assets or whatever is taking up all that space

I'm doubting that the code compile alone results in such a large .exe file, but suggest the issue is not a bunch of nuget libraries, but that of bloated picture or some other kind of assets being included here. You really don't' have much choice in this area, but it's doubtful the compiled code is the bulk of the 80+ megs resulting project. So, one road could be removing out the assets into a separate folder, and then adding some means to check, or pull down the assets on startup for those that are missing.  On the other hand, as suggested, a reduction in 30 megs not going help much.

Thanks for valuable feedback. Are there any recommended tools that can help me find and  remove any unused forms, files, icons, images, dll in my project ?

Remove or replace unnecessary dependencies.
Compress large resource files, such as large images, etc.
Also consider using Trim self-contained deployments and executables.

Is there any specific tool that can help me identify  and remove any unused forms, files, icons, images, dll? We are using lot of references in our project that have dependencies across multiple projects.. Identifying is a challenge.
